# Gerar números aleatórios em Java

Tags: java, random

Como gerar só números maiores que 2?

Como gerar só números maiores que 2 e os números gerados têm que serem múltiplos de 3(eg. 3, 6, 9)?

Como gerar só números menores que 10?

Como gerar só números menores que 10 e os números gerados têm que serem múltiplos de 3(eg. 3, 6, 9)?

Comment: Você pode utilizar a classe Random?

Comment: pode utilizar a class random: Random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min onde min seria 2, agora as próximas situações acredito que deva fazer verificações em uma função recursiva para retornar apenas os resultados desejados...

Comment: Sim. Posso ser com Random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instanciando a classe `Random`:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

> Como gerar só números maiores que 2?

Entre 2 e 1000, podendo substituir o mil ou dois por qualquer valor, por exemplo:

```
numero = random.nextInt(1000) + 2;
```

> Como gerar só números maiores que 2 e os números gerados têm que serem
>   múltiplos de 3 (ex. 3, 6, 9)?

Entre 3 e 3003 todos múltiplos de 3.

```
numero = (random.nextInt(1000) + 1) * 3;
```

> Como gerar só números menores que 10?

```
numero = random.nextInt(10);
```

> Como gerar só números menores que 10 e os números gerados têm que
>   serem múltiplos de 3(eg. 3, 6, 9)?

```
numero = (random.nextInt(2)+1) * 3;
```

> Gerar números negativos, por exemplo de -5000 a 5000

```
numero = ((random.nextInt(2000)) * 5) - 5000;
```